# Can't extend disk/partition. vmware

Tags: vmware

I'm having some issues extending one of our linux servers that I have inherited. I'm not really sure what the previous admin has done and my linux skills are lacking.

I tried to do the normal, extend disk in vmware, boot server up and through fdisk creating a new partition /dev/sda3 but I'm unable to get more then a few blocks when creating it.

Also I would like to fix the errors I receive ofcourse. Disk /dev/mapper/JIRA-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Anyone able to help?:) I have a clone of the server so I am able to test anything on it. But for now I have not been able to do anything but ruin the system.

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19581 cylinders, total 314572800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000180c3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   104855551    52176897    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   104855551    52176896   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/JIRA-root: 49.1 GB, 49102716928 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5969 cylinders, total 95903744 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/JIRA-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/JIRA-swap_1: 4290 MB, 4290772992 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 521 cylinders, total 8380416 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/JIRA-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

---

```
fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/JIRA-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6171c5ce-6ef5-420a-ad9c-c8bb1111a528 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/JIRA-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: I would suggest to create a new machine and migrate the jira installation there. This should be a few hours work, while you already spend some hours on trial and error on growing the images and filesystems.

Comment: (sorry, deleted comment was wrong.)
you will not be able to create a new sda3 as this would have to be placed between sda2 and sda5 but there is not enough diskspace free. What you should try is to create a new volume using the lvm toolset at the end of the disk. resizing images mostly appends more space at the end of the image file.